# not syncing: No init found. for jffs2 filesystem

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, filesystems, ramdisk, jffs2

I am working on mpc8309-twr board with kernel 2.6.33.7, 
when i am creating my rootfs image with ramdisk file system (rootfs.ext2.gz.uboot) i am able to mount my file system and 
my board is able to boot successfully.

```
But, when i am trying with jffs2 filesystem it is saying "no init found",here is the kernel log.
```

> > VFS: Mounted root (jffs2 filesystem) on device 31:1. Freeing unused kernel memory: 168k init Warning: unable to open an initial console.
> >     Kernel panic - not syncing: No init found.  Try passing init= option
> >     to kernel. Call Trace: [c782df40] [c0008484] 0xc0008484 (unreliable)
> >     [c782df70] [c0025320] 0xc0025320 [c782dfc0] [c0003b78] 0xc0003b78
> >     [c782dfd0] [c03a2238] 0xc03a2238 [c782dff0] [c0011994] 0xc0011994

But init is present at /sbin/init location. can any one help me in this.

```
Thanks in advance...............!
```

Comment: can you tell which primary memory device this board is having, kernel command line argument and the part of dts file for memory device support

Comment: @SamratDas i am using DDR2 primary memory and it is of 128MB, the bootargs are as follows                                          bootargs=root=/dev/mtdblock1 rootfstype=jffs2 rw console=ttyS0,115200                               and i am using the u-boot-2010.06 version.  and i am using this /dev/mtdblock1 as my filesystem partition.

Comment: memory device i mean storage memory? NAND/NOR, mmc/emmc or any other ?

Comment: ok ok i am using NOR flash for storing images uImage , rootfs.jffs2, mpc8309twr.dtb. @SamratDas

Comment: little more kernel log i need, where the kernel probe the flash memory and creates partitions

Comment: @SamratDas please follow the link for kernel log ----->  (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6NLYO9x28pfSmhrdF9XTE4yTTA)

Comment: did you provided proper partition table in device blob tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While working with flash memories, we need to provide partition table to kernel manually through device tree blob. As RAM image have everything proper so booting in proper manner.

But when you try to boot with your NOR flash your kernel log says `RedBoot partition parsing not available`, which means the offset kernel using for loading the rootfs might not be same as exact where rootfs is present. Due to which kernel is unable to find your `init` as well as `initial console` as per your kernel log.

So add or change the offset of the partitions you are providing in the device tree structure file.

You can refer to [this](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/mtd/) documentation for reference for adding mtd support in device tree file.

Comment: thanks for your help @samratdas but the partition which you are mentioning aren't they same for both ramdisk and jffs2 filesystem??????     this **redboot partition parsing not availabe** is been present in ramdisk also but at that time there is no such error of **No init found**.......!

Comment: partition size and offset may be same but the way how rootfs comes into picture in both cases are different in case of ram disk, your bootloader is responsible for loading ramdisk, in case of root partition is provided to kernel which came into the role after disk mounted as per partition. In case of booting with jffs2, kernel is creating random partition and loading as per given argument where offsets were wrong, whereas in ram disk bootloader taking it from proper offset and in this case proper partitioning for kernel dosn't matter.

Comment: are you having any more documents or links that could give me more information on this........???

Comment: these things i learnt from experience, but general topics regarding these you can learn from - [The Linux Document Project](http://www.tldp.org/) (full of reference) | [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) (you can learn how whole thing is working) | [Few general learning material](http://free-electrons.com/docs/)